# Simular _GET php em string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Eu tenho uma string simular á:

```
<li><a title="string" href="http://geting.com/?v=123?t=abc">Opção 1</a></li>
```

Eu gostaria de algo que pegasse o parâmetro `?v=`, só ele, igual quando pegamos no método `$_GET["v"]`.

Como poderia fazer isso? Acredito que `preg_match` poderia me ajudar, mas não entendo sobre?

```
$string = '<li><a title="string" href="http://geting.com/?v=123?t=abc">Opção 1</a></li>';
echo preg_match('regex',$string);
```

Resultado desejado: 123

Comment: https://ideone.com/wHNt0v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seu link esta incorreto o formato normal é `?v=123&t=abc`, ou seja o segundo `?` deve ser um `&`.

Acho que voce pode utilizar duas funções php para isso, a [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php)

Com a primeira você faz o parse da url e pega a `query`.

A segunda transforma a `query` em um array.

```
$url = "http://geting.com/?v=123&t=abc";
$parse = parse_url( $url );
parse_str( $parse['query'],$query );
echo $query['v'];
```

*Obs.: O codigo acima não foi testado, mas essa é a ideia =)*

*Edição

Caso você precise extrair a `url` do texto, você pode utilizar o seguinte codigo

```
$li = '<li><a title="string" href="http://geting.com/?v=123&t=abc">Opção 1</a></li>';
preg_match_all("/\"(.*?)\"/",$li,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Correto! Muito obrigado por seu tempo.